# Question about deep copying example

Tags: iphone, objective-c, categories, nscoding

In the Beginning iPhone 4 book, the author has this code to create a category for creating a deep copy of an NSDictionary that has an NSArray of names for each letter of the alphabet to show an example of an indexed table with a search bar.

```
#import "NSDictionary-MutableDeepCopy.h"
@implementation NSDictionary (MutableDeepCopy)
- (NSMutableDictionary *) mutableDeepCopy { 
    NSMutableDictionary *returnDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:[self count]]; 
    NSArray *keys = [self allKeys]; 
    for (id key in keys) {
        id oneValue = [self valueForKey:key]; 
        id oneCopy = nil;
        if ([oneValue respondsToSelector:@selector(mutableDeepCopy)]) oneCopy = [oneValue mutableDeepCopy];
        else if ([oneValue respondsToSelector:@selector(mutableCopy)]) oneCopy = [oneValue mutableCopy];
        if (oneCopy == nil) 
           oneCopy = [oneValue copy];
        [returnDict setValue:oneCopy forKey:key]; 
        [oneCopy release];
    } 
    return returnDict;
} 

@end
```

Can someone explain the for loop logic?  I'm not sure what he's trying to do in seeing which value responds to which selector, and why it would be added to the dictionary.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, the for loop simply iterates through all the keys in the dictionary. Beforehand, we create a new dictionary called `returnDict` - this will be what we return.

For each key in the dictionary we want to copy, we...

1. Get the object stored for that key (`[self valueForKey:key]`), and save it into a variable called `oneValue`.
2. If `oneValue` implements our `mutableDeepCopy` method (ie, it's an `NSDictionary`) go call it, and assign the return value into a variable called `oneCopy`.
3. Else, we see if `oneCopy` implements the `mutableCopy` method. If it does, we put the output into the `oneCopy` variable.
4. At this point, we check to see if following steps (2) and (3) the `oneCopy` variable has had anything assigned to it (`if (oneCopy == nil)`). If it doesn't (ie, it's equal to `nil`) we can assume the object doesn't implement either `mutableDeepCopy` or `mutableCopy`, so we instead call a plain old `copy` and assign its value to `oneCopy`.
5. Add `oneCopy` into our `returnDict` dictionary using the original key.

That's the for loop - at the end of it all, we go and return the copied dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

The logic in the for-loop is convoluted because the author is trying to get as mutable and as deep a copy of the entire array as possible. The code tries three different ways to satisfy this, in order of preference:

- Use `mutableDeepCopy` if possible (if the object understands that message).
- Otherwise, use `mutableCopy` if possible.
- If all else fails, just use `copy`.

If the object is just plain not copiable, your code goes boom when it sends the object `-copy`, since no test is made for whether the object responds to `-copy`. This is appropriate, since trying to deep copy an array containing items that cannot be copied is definitely programmer error.